Un mot en francais pour "backstabber"?
N'y a-t-il pas de mot francais pour "backstabber" ?
Il y a "traitre" mais ce n'est pas la même chose.
Je cherche sur Google mais il répond toujours avec une locution.

Cela dépend grandement du contexte.

@Toto Context? Simplement quelqu'un qui poignarde un autre dans le dos figurativement!

Pourquoi traitre ne conviendrait pas?

Le contexte importe beaucoup.
Si l'on parle de façon figurée, il existe probablement un mot ou une expression courte qui convient (traître, faux frère, judas, aigrefin, etc.), dépendant là encore du contexte.
Si l'on parle de quelqu'un qui poignarde effectivement quelqu'un dans le dos, il faut parler du geste et/ou de l'arme utilisée pour que ça ait du sens.
Dans ce cas, il n'y a pas vraiment de mot ou d'expression pour cela, il faut expliquer avec une phrase.
Le mot « poignardeur » a été quelques fois utilisé, mais il n'est dans aucun dictionnaire moderne (à part le Wiktionnaire qui cite le Littré de 1873, et des exemples littéraires, ou où le mot est entre guillemets).
Donner une réponse simple à une telle question ouverte est très difficile, donner la phrase en question et éventuellement le passage permettrait certainement une réponse immédiate.

Comme de coutume avec l'anglais, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une traduction exacte. "Backstabber" porte bien la notion de traîtrise, mais "traître" est plus en rapport avec un état, une organisation.
Si vous pensez à une action contre une personne, alors il y aurait peut être "perfide", "fourbe", ou plus familier "faux-jeton", "faux-cul".

Faux-cul oui, ou encore langue de vipère, voire langue de pute (@stackOverblown: very rude).

@jlliagre Quoi? Was? What? Je ne comprend pas!

@jlliagre Merci beaucoup pour le edit?

@stackoverblown NP, I just mean langue de pute is very rude, not you :-)

faux-jeton = faux-cul = hypocrite, qui n'est pas connoté "adepte de la violence-surprise". Pour ça, nous avons faux-frère.

Un terme plus litteraire pour "langue de pute" est sycophante ...

@Graffito Oui, carrément à l'autre extrémité du registre ! :-)

Et le mot "sycophante" étant un faux-ami entre le français et l'anglais, on a bouclé la boucle du "traitre" ;-)
